# Как найти суммы одинаковых отрицательных элементов массива?

Tags: c++

*Задача.*

Задан одномерный массив А(10) целых чисел. Ввести массив в теле программы. Найдите суммы одинаковых отрицательных элементов массива и произведения положительных элементов массива. Нахождение сумм отрицательных чисел и произведения положительных элементов массива оформить в виде двух подпрограмм функций. Результат вывести в основной программе.

Вот мой код:

```
int main()
{
int const N=10 ;
 int S=0,K=0;
int A[N]={1, -2, 2, -2, 5, -2, 7, 8, 9, 1};

for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
 if (A[i]<0)
{ 
   for (int j=0;j <N-1;j++)
     {
     if(A[i]==A[j] && K==0 && i!=j)
          {
             K=2;
             A[j]=0;    

          }
          else if (A[i]=A[j] && i!=j)
          {
            K++;
            A[j]=0;
          }
    }
          if (K>1)
          S+=A[i]*K;
          K=0;      
     }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "И чо?" (с). Есть какое-то задание, какой-то код. Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: этот код не работает , как правильно его сделать через переменную , которая отвечала бы за переход к сравниванию следующего элемента массива при повторении

Comment: Как у вас код не работает - знаете только вы. Подумайте об этом.

Comment: @user193288 А произведения должны быть выполнены также для одинаковых положительных чисел или же одно произведение для всех положительных чисел?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow для всех положительных

Comment: @user193288 И что с ними делать? Надо где-то сохранить или просто вывести на консоль?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow просто вывести

Comment: Когда же наконец студенты-двоечники исчезнут с нашего сайта? Отладчик в руки и отлаживайте!

Comment: @ VladD попросила знакомая , я просто пытаюсь хоть чем-то помочь ( у меня специальность другая )

Comment: @user193288 У вас сказано, что вы должны написать функции. Как одна функция может возвратить несколько сумм одинаковых отрицательных элементов? Вы вектора проходили?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow нет, препод дал сразу указатели, сказав что это самостоятельно очень легко пройти

Comment: @user193288 Мне представляется, что задание вами сформулировано неточно. Уже один факт, что вы в описании задания используете слово произведение во множественном числе, а потом выясняется, что нужно лишь одно произведение, наводит на мысль, что вы неправильно формулируете задание.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/T9n4B4

```
#include <cstdio>

constexpr const int a[] = {1, -2, 2, -2, 5, -2, 7, 8, 9, 1};
constexpr const unsigned n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

template <const int *x, unsigned i=0, long long t=1> class c
  {
  public:
    const static long long p = c<x, i+1, x[i]<0 ? t**(x+i) : t>::p;
    const static long long s = c<x, i+1, (x[i]>0) ? t+x[i] : t>::s;
  };

template <const int *x, long long t> class c<x, n, t>
  {
  public:
    const static long long p = t;
    const static long long s = t-1;
  };

constexpr long long p()
  {
  return c<a>::p;
  }

constexpr long long s()
  {
  return c<a>::s;
  }

int main(void)
  {
  return !printf("%Ld\n%Ld\n", p(), s());
  }
```

Результат:

```
-8
33
```